# How to return latest distinct rows in elasticsearch ignoring a timestamp field

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I have documents like:

```
{'foo': 'foo', 'bar': 'bar', ..., 'timestamp': 3}
{'foo': 'diffval', 'bar': 'diffval', ..., 'timestamp': 2}
{'foo': 'foo', 'bar': 'bar', ..., 'timestamp': 2}
{'foo': 'foo', 'bar': 'bar', ..., 'timestamp': 1}
```

Which I search for via `_search?from=0&size=20&sort=timestamp%3Adesc`

I would like to now search for just the latest distinct row - e.g:

```
{'foo': 'foo', 'bar': 'bar', ..., 'timestamp': 3}
{'foo': 'diffval', 'bar': 'diffval', ..., 'timestamp': 2}
```

But I would like to do this without explicitly indicating the `foo`, `bar`, fields as there could be a lot and are not consistently there - the `timestamp` field however is consistent.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a sollution where I create a `hash` field of all the fields apart from the timestamp before storing in the document. Then I use the collapse functionality in opensearch - the hits will then return the latest distinct hash.

```
GET /.../_search?sort=timestamp%3Adesc
{
  "collapse": {
    "field": "hash",
    "inner_hits": {
      "name": "",
      "size": 0,
      "sort": [
        {
          "timestamp": {
            "order": "desc"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please have a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72525749/get-most-recent-distinct-rows-from-aws-opensearchelasticsearch